# FindObjectsByType<> Is Never Working, for some reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm trying to make a save load system for my level editor game. and i need to use this function, but it never worked for me, everytime i would try to use it just didn't work, all of the other time i would find other solution to avoid using it, but now i really need it. i honesty don't know what i'm doing wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SaveScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Block[] Blocks;
    private DataService dataService = new JsonDataService();

    private List<float> Ids;

    public void Save()
    {
        //This Doesn't Work
        Blocks = FindObjectsByType<Block>(FindObjectsSortMode.None);

        print(Blocks);

        if (Blocks.Length > 0)
        {
            foreach (Block Block in Blocks)
            {
                Ids.Add(Block.id);
            }
        }

        dataService.SaveData("/Level.json", Ids);
    }
}
```

By the way, it might help to know that when i remove "(FindObjectsSortMode.None)" it gives me an error.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work". The list is empty?  It throws an exception?  What was the actual error you got?

Comment: Yes The Blocks Variable is empty

Comment: When i remove That part it says, error CS1501: No overload for method 'FindObjectsByType' takes 0 arguments

Comment: are you sure there are some in scene? and are active?

Comment: The docs say:  _"This doesn't return Assets (for example meshes, textures, or prefabs). It also doesn't return objects that have HideFlags.DontSave set. Use Resources.FindObjectsOfTypeAll to avoid these limitations."_  I wonder if any of these conditions apply to you and if you have different results calling `FindObjectsOfTypeAll`?

Comment: i tried FindObjectsOfTypeAll and i got the same result, null. and yes i have gameobjects in the scene with the block script and active.

Comment: wait i'm getting somewhere

Comment: Honestly i gave up, i'm using tags

Comment: Solved the problem was the list variable

Comment: and i needed to use FindObjectsOfTypeAll, so thanks a lot